# How to draw border around canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am drawing an image on a canvas with white background color. I want to draw a border around the canvas and I am unable to do so. Here is my code:

```
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.font = "50px Arial";
context.fillText(chartId, 0, 50);
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);//for white background
```

after this i want a red border to appear around the whole canvas.

Comment: @blex doesn't seem to be working,I am seeing no border

Comment: Ok, `canvas.style.border = '1px solid red';` is just adding a CSS border around the canvas, not drawing it on it. [See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/fbg8r9b2/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `context.lineWidth` to `2`, set `context.strokeStyle` to `#FF0000"`, and use `context.strokeRect`, not `fillRect`. 
`globalCompositeOperation` if set to `destination-over`, then the newly apply thing will use canvas's value, so change to `source-over`. Used `lightblue` to fake the `drawImage` in your code

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 300;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.font = "50px Arial";
context.fillText('ASD', 0, 50);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
context.fillStyle = "#00FFFF";
context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);//for white background
context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
context.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);//for white background
```

```html
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
```

Comment: What about if i want to put borders outline?
Fox example: width:100 height:100 border-width:5
Final size: width:110 height:110

Thanks in advance,
Chris Pappas

Comment: @ChrisP I'm not sure I get your question, if you mean you want a border outside of the canvas, why not just use css border instead, [for example](https://jsfiddle.net/vczf4tye/)

Comment: @fuyushimoya the problem is, if you need to download the canvas content as an image the border will not be included